# How to retrieve the auto incremented ID using slick / plainSQL?

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, playframework, slick

Isn't there a slick/plainSQL native solution to retrieve the auto incremented id of the current INSERT?

userId is an auto incremental field in my mySQL table.

```
sql"""
   INSERT INTO `table`(`email`) 
   OUTPUT INSERTED.userId 
   VALUES ("theEmailAdress@test.de")
""".as[Int].firstOption
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers 
Oliver

Comment: Oliver, PLEASE cross-link topics when you cross post with the mailing list https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/scalaquery/f0842022-0e62-4fab-b0e9-fb13e77f5bd9%40googlegroups.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [cvogt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467390/cvogt) for helping out in this discussion.
I think it would be helpful to submit a PR, inasmuch as it is a very common and useful functionality which should not be missing in [slick's plainSQL queries](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/sql.html).

Finally, i found a work-around to replace the missing native function as following.

Within the same session I settle two queries. The first one is the `INSERT` statement, the second statement is `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` which returns the newest automatically generated value that was set for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the recently executed `INSERT`(1). More details here: [MySQL Reference - LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html)

```
Database.forDataSource(dataSource).withDynSession {
  sqlu"""INSERT INTO `users`(`email`) VALUES ("theEmailAdress@test.de")
  """.firstOption match {
    case Some(num) if num == 1 => sql"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()".as[Long].firstOption()
    case None => None
  }
}
```

This works for me right now. If there are any improvements, do not hesitate to post your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the database.

For MS SQL it's SCOPE_IDENTITY(), for mySQL it's LAST_INSERT_ID(). 
Try searching for equivalent for your DB if it's none of the above.

**Added by cvogt**:

There is currently no slick-built-in feature for plain SQL for this and no way to access the underlying jdbc statement when using Slick's `sql"..."` interpolation or `StaticQuery`, which would allow you to access `getGeneratedKeys`. You could probably patch the [SQL interpolator](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.0/slick-testkit/src/test/scala/scala/slick/test/direct/QueryableTest.scala) and [StatementInvoker](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.0/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc/StatementInvoker.scala) to allow this. They are just 150 LOC. Maybe worth giving a shot and submitting a PR.

You could however use one of the [Slick session](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1-RC1/api/#scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend%24SessionDef) method like `withPreparedInsertStatement`, which wrap [jdbc connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) methods to work with a jdbc statement. I created a PR to add documentation about this: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/691

Comment: Thanks for the quick answere. But this is not the solution Iam looking for: INSERT INTO `table`(`email`) VALUES ("theEmailAdress@test.de");
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); Arent there slick on-board native tools?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by that. 
AFAIK this is the only common solution and I never had a reason to search for something else.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding directly to the answer.